# Plot contours obtained from one image over another

Tags: python, matlab

How does one plot contours obtained from one image over another image?

My `original` image and `changes` image are same sized, but `changes` has only some of the part of `original`. I want these parts to get highlighted in color on `original`

I have the python code for the same:

```
original   = cv2.imread(image1_path)     #this should be background
changes    = cv2.imread(image2_path)     #contours found from this should come over original    
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(changes,127,255,0)    
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,
                                              cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
img = cv2.drawContours(original, contours, -1,(0,0,255), 2)
```

How to do same in Matlab?

**EDIT**

```
changes  = imread('changes.jpg');
original = imread('original.jpg')
c        = edge(changes,'canny');
original(:,:,1) = original;                           
original(:,:,2) = original(:,:,1);                    
original(:,:,3) = original(:,:,1);
imshow(original+repmat(uint8(c),[1,1,3])*255);
```

Comment: a couple of questions:

1. do you need to call OpenCV from Matlab or just need the functional equivalent?
2. how precisely the result has to match the results of OpenCV (i.e. the contour finding algorithm - does it have to be exact?)
3. can you use a MATLAB-Python bridge (e.g. [matpy](http://algoholic.eu/matpy/)) to literally call the same Python code from within MATLAB using MATLAB data?

Comment: @ALGOholic 1.I would very much like to have the functional equivalents. 2.Precision is not an issue (as of now). 3. I don't know how to do that but now that you have mentioned, I'm going to look into it. So, does Matlab have the function equivalents that I want?

Comment: I forgot to ask the 4th question - whether you have Image Processing Toolbox available in MATLAB? There are imcontour() and edge() for example. One way you could do is: im=imread('braincube.png'); c=edge(rgb2gray(im),'canny'); imshow(im+repmat(uint8(c),[1,1,3])*255) where braincube.png is an RGB image, if it's greyscale you could skip the rgb2gray() and the repmat(). If you need to threshold, you can just put im>127 for example in edge(rgb2gray(im)>127, 'canny');

Comment: @ALGOholic I did something like that. Problem is the `changes` are getting displayed in white instead of some color over `original`. See what I did in the edit I made to the question.

Comment: you could do e.g. `c2=bsxfun(@times, repmat(c, [1,1,3]), reshape([255,-255,-255],[1,1,3])); imshow(uint8(double(im)+c2))` to show the outlines in red. does this answer your concern? or are you trying to say that you would like them to be filled?

Comment: That's perfect! Is there any way I can save these `changes` shown in red over `original` as a `jpg` or `png` file? Basically can I save what `imshow()` is showing to a file?

Comment: Sure, just imwrite(uint8(double(im)+c2), 'output.png'); I'll add the whole code as the answer.

Comment: I got it, how to save the output of `imshow()` to a `jpg` file. Thank you for your help. You could write it as an answer.

Comment: Yeah please do that. I will happy to accept it then. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw contours in red over the original image and save the output to a file the way to go is the following:

```
im=imread('braincube.png');
c=edge(rgb2gray(im),'canny');
% c=imdilate(c, strel('disk', 2)); % optional increase thickness
c2=bsxfun(@times, repmat(c, [1,1,3]), reshape([255,-255,-255],[1,1,3]));
imwrite(uint8(double(im)+c2), 'output.png');
```

Comment: One more thing though, could I increase the thickness of the red lines. Not that it's "highly" important, but it's desirable to me.

Comment: you can do e.g. c=imdilate(c, strel('disk', 3)); before creating c2; and you can replace 3 with another integer - this affects thickness.